# "Каковы польза и вред" или "Какова польза и вред"?

Tags: определения, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно? Множественное или единственное число?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, *каковы*, в данном случае, какая часть речи? Определение или нет?

Comment: Возможно в разных контекстах и множественное, и единственное число. Что же до части речи... Краткая форма прилагательного КАКОВОЙ. _"Определение или **нет**?"_ -- Скорее всего, верно второе: НЕТ.

Answer (score 4):

Интуиция подсказывает мне вариант "**Каковы польза и вред**?". В поисках подтверждения я обратился к Нацкорпусу. Действительно, в большинстве подобных конструкций используется множественное число, хотя встречается и единственное. Скорее всего, оба варианта допустимы. Судите сами:

**Множественное число:**

... **каковы** смысл и предназначение этой информации. [О критическом состоянии учета миграции в России (2004) // «Вопросы статистики», 2004.10.28]

Вопрос: **Каковы** характер и динамика развития современных российско-египетских отношений? [Ответы официального представителя МИД России на вопросы российских СМИ по российско-египетским отношениям (2004) // «Дипломатический вестник», 2004.06.29]

Вопрос: **Каковы** характер и динамика развития российско-сербско-черногорских отношений в настоящее время? [Ответы официального представителя МИД России на вопросы российских СМИ по российско-сербско-черногорским отношениям]

― **Каковы** место и роль ВДВ в современной войне? [Олег Одноколенко. Элита на контракте (2003) // «Итоги», 2003.03.04]

В связи с этим возникает вопрос: **каковы** место и роль нейропсихологии в клинической психологии? [Е. Д. Хомская. Клиническая психология и нейропсихология: целое или часть? (2003) // «Вопросы психологии», 2003.10.21]

**Каковы** логика и динамика развития национальной художественной мысли? [Рубен Ангаладян. Параджанов: коллаж тени и цвета в диапазоне одного человеческого сердца // «Звезда», 2001]

В результате у Анны Андреевны появилось стремление самой объяснять каждому, **каковы** значение и смысл «Поэмы без героя». [Эмма Герштейн. Книга жизни (1994)]

**Единственное число:**

А **какова** осадка и дедвейт? ― спросил дядя Жора, стоя за спиной рулевого и подмигивая мне: мы, дескать, тоже, корабелы. [Дмитрий Каралис. Катер (2002-2003)]  [омонимия не снята]  ←…→

**Каков** механизм и природа «хорошего» и «плохого» понимания, остается нераскрытым: то ли он коренится в психологии, то ли в гносеологии, но совершенно ясно, что не в знаковом отношении, из которого исходил Гоббс. [С. С. Неретина, А. П. Огурцов. Пути к универсалиям. Раздел IV. Универсалии как идеи: от номинализма к реализму (2006)]

**Какова** причина и природа этого навязчивого видения, этого дежа вю? [А. Е. 
Рекемчук. Мамонты (2006)]

**Каково** настроение и общее состояние собаки? И тогда на многие вопросы, касающиеся оптимального рациона животного, вы сможете ответить самостоятельно. [Елена Дубровина. Что едят собаки? (2002) // «Homes & Gardens», 2002.06.20]

**Какова** цена и степень независимости Казахстана? ― Независимость пришла к нам в результате распада союзного государства, пришла мирным путем, но от этого она не перестает быть величайшей ценностью. [Нурсултан Назарбаев: «Легких дел в политике не бывает» (2002) // «Известия», 2002.04.03]

Answer (score 3):

1) **КАКОВ**, -а, -о. I. **местоим. прил. в функц. сказ.** 1. Употр. как вопросительное слово о качестве, свойстве кого-, чего-л. А какова у вас река? Все спрашивали, каков урожай в хозяйстве.

2) По Розенталю надо выбирать  вариант ед. числа: **какова польза и вред**. Этот вариант  в большей степени соответствует приведенному правилу.

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_05](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_05)

**Определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным – однородным членам, ставится в форме единственного числа:**
1)      если по смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующим, например:каждый завод и фабрика; уличный шум и грохот; летний жар и зной; морской прилив и отлив.

3) Фактически **при совпадении рода существительных используется форма ед. числа**, так как в этом случае возможно **согласование в роде с ближайшим существительным**. Е**сли род не совпадает, лучше использовать вариант мн. числа,** так как согласование всё равно отсутствует (так называемый выбор по смыслу,  а не по форме): **Каковы польза и вред.**

Comment: В примерах Розенталь приводит разные варианты для существительных, различающихся грамматическим родом (как и в нашем случае): "мои отец и мать" (Чехов) и "моим отцом и матерью" (Аксаков; такая возможность - на мой взгляд, спорная - списывается Розенталем на падеж, отличный от именительного).

Comment: Каждый завод и фабрика; уличный шум и грохот - разные примеры, род может совпадать или нет.

Comment: _Jasmin: 2) По Розенталю надо выбирать вариант ед. числа: какова польза и вред. Этот вариант в большей степени соответствует приведенному правилу.
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_05. **Определение**, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным – однородным членам, ставится в форме единственного числа…_ === **А это-то тут при чём?** Разве в разбираемом у нас предложении есть ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ? Нет его. Есть СКАЗУЕМОЕ. Вы же даёте ссылку на параграф 195 из Розенталя, называемый "**Определение** при существительных – однородных членах".

Comment: Это местоименное прилагательное в роли сказуемого (см. начало ответа). Кстати, для сказуемого в препозиции Розенталь рекомендует ед. число. Также он говорит о желательности согласования в роде с ближайшим существительным. Факторов называется много, но вот общая идея , которая регулировала бы все эти частные решения, не формулируется. А то для сказуемых - одно, для прилагательных - другое,  для местоименных. сказуемых - третье. Вот задача для филологов, которым нечего делать и хочется что-то "пореформировать".  Написали бы общее, всем понятное правило на эту тему на основании частных решений.